# Why am I getting a "does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments" error? C#

Tags: c#, constructor, arguments

On my form load, I have this code:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CharityCyclists cyclist1 = new CharityCyclists();
        CharityCyclists cyclist2 = new CharityCyclists("a", 1, "Finished", 0, 0, 0, "One Wheel", 1, 500);

        cyclist1.Type = "Novelty Charity Cyclist";
        cyclist1.Number = 1;
        cyclist1.Finished = "Not Finished";
        cyclist1.Hours = 0;
        cyclist1.Mins = 0;
        cyclist1.Secs = 0;
        cyclist1.Bicycle = "Tricycle";
        cyclist1.Wheels = 3;
        cyclist1.FundsRaised = 300;
    }
```

However, I'm getting a error saying "'CycleEvent.CharityCyclists' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments", it says the error is to do with this part of the code:

```
CharityCyclists cyclist1 = new CharityCyclists();
```

Here is my CharityCyclists class:

```
class CharityCyclists : Cyclists
{
    private string bicycle;
    private int wheels;
    private double fundsRaised;

    public string Bicycle
    {
        get { return bicycle; }
        set { bicycle = value; }
    }

    public int Wheels
    {
        get { return wheels; }
        set { wheels = value; }
    }

    public double FundsRaised
    {
        get { return fundsRaised; }
        set { fundsRaised = value; }
    }

    public CharityCyclists(String type, int number, String finished, int hours, int mins, int secs, string bicycle, int wheels, double fundsRaised) : base(type, number, finished, hours, mins, secs, fundsRaised)
    {
        this.bicycle = bicycle;
        this.wheels = wheels;
        this.FundsRaised = fundsRaised;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString() + " riding a " + bicycle + " with " + wheels + " wheels" ;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What part of the error do you not understand?

Comment: Because you don't have a constructor like `public CharityCyclists(){}`

Comment: I presume the poster is coming from a C++ background, where the compiler will generate a default c'tor.  The answers below will explain that C# does not generate a default constructor.

Comment: @DonalLafferty: C++ won't create a default ctor either under the same situations.  In this C++ and C# (and Java) behave the same.  Once you explicitly create a constructor, it will no longer generate the "default" constructor.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That is because the `CharityCyclists` class does not have a constructor that takes no arguments.

The C# compiler will generate the default constructor for you, *if you define no other constructors*.
If you define a constructor yourself (as you have), the C# compiler will not generate a default constructor.

If you want to allow `CharityCyclists` to be constructed without parameters, add this code to the class:

```
public CharityCyclists() 
{}
```

Comment: This is incorrect.  The base class "Cyclist" is the one expecting the parameters.  You need to add in the :base(param) syntax to make CharityCyclists have no arguments.

Comment: @GalacticJello: not sure that we know that...  he doesn't have code posted for Cyclist, it may well have a parameterless constructor.  If Cyclists has a parameterless constructor the driis's code will work fine, if it doesn't, then yes driis's parameterized constructor would need to make an explicit call to the base class constructor with the arguments expected.

Comment: Look at the CharityCyclists constructor, it is hidden on the end: `public CharityCyclists(String type, int number, String finished, int hours, int mins, int secs, string bicycle, int wheels, double fundsRaised) : base(type, number, finished, hours, mins, secs, fundsRaised)`

Comment: @GalacticJello: That's only *one* possible constructor of `Cyclists`, without seeing the full definition of `Cyclists` we have no way of knowing if other overloaded constructors exist...  He may have `Cyclists() { }` and Cyclists(String, int, String, int, int, int, double) { }` for example...  Thus, if there *is* a parameterless constructor on `Cyclists`, the explicit call to `base` is unnecessary.

Comment: @James Michael Hare: Sure, but 9 times out of 10, this error means you need to supply parameters for the base class (in my experience).

Comment: @GalacticJello: No, the error *literally* means `CharityCyclists` doesn't have a parameterless constructor, it says nothing about what the base class constructor does or does not have.  You would get the *exact* same error even if `CharityCyclists` didn't derive from `Cyclists`.  Exact same error.

Comment: @James - What about about a base class with only a parametered construtor?   Adding a parameterless constructor in the outer class will result in the error unless you provide the base class what it needs: `class Cyclists
    {
        public Cyclists(String type, int number, String finished, int hours, int mins, int secs, double fundsRaised)
        {
        }
    }

    class CharityCyclists : Cyclists
    {

        public CharityCyclists()
        {
        }
    }`

Comment: @GalacticJello: In that case you would get an error on a *different* line of code as well.  The error clearly indicated it was at the point of instantiating `CharityCyclists`.  Since we don't *see* what he has for `Cyclists` you are operating on presumption only.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19183/discussion-between-galacticjello-and-james-michael-hare)

Comment: @GalacticJello: My whole point is: you cannot possibly assert "This is incorrect" about driis's response without seeing what `Cyclists` is defined as, you are answering based on conjecture only.  It is *possible* driis's answer may be incomplete based on assumptions about what unknown code may or may not exist.  You would have been *more* correct to say, "your answer is assuming Cyclists has a parameterless constructor, if it does not then you should...".  but to jump straight into "this is incorrect" was where I begged to differ.

Comment: @John- Yes, I was incorrect to say incorrect. Apologies.  But for the folks joining us at home, watch your base class parameters as well.

Answer (score 2):

When you provided a constructor for your class that takes arguments, the compiler no longer creates an empty constructor.

Therefore, you cannot call an empty constructor because it does not exist.
You would need to explicitly write the constructor that takes 0 arguments in your class's code.

Comment: Be careful of the phrase "empty constructor", typically the compiler generates a *default* constructor that calls the *parameterless* constructor of the base class.  It isn't truly *empty* as the IL may include field initializations, etc, generated by the compiler.

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare Thanks for that explanation. I'm not sure what IL is though. Could you help me out?

Comment: IL is the Intermediate Language that all .NET languages compile into.

Answer (score 1):

If you declare a constructor classes do not automatically get a default constructor.  You will need to create a parameterless constructor to resolve the issue, or call the one that accepts the parameters.

Comment: Watch out on "create a default constructor", this is slightly misleading.  The default constructor is the one the compiler generates for you when no other constructor exists.  When you create a constructor without arguments, you are creating a *parameterless* constructor.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645608(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare I guess I didn't realize there was different terminology for the two. I always just refered to the parameterless constructor as the default wether I created it or the compiler did. Thanks

Comment: it's one of those terms that may mean different things to different people, so it's best to go with MSDN's descriptions when speaking of C#.  The `? :` operator is another.  C++ developers often call this the "ternary" operator, but C# explicitly calls it the "conditional" operator.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a consturctor that takes no arguments.

you need to add

```
public CharityCyclists()
{
    this.bicycle = "bike";
    this.wheels = 2;
    this.FundsRaised = 0;
}
```

or something like that

Answer (score 1):

When you create a constructor that does not contain 0 arguments, you automatically remove the default [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115%28VS.80%29.aspx).  You should create a new default constructor (with no arguments) and that will take care of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have any constructors, C# will implicitly create an empty one for you.  It's functionally the same thing as you writing:

```
public CharityCyclists()
{
}
```

It only does this if you have *no* constructors, though.  You have one, so this doesn't happen.  You need to explicitly create a constructor that takes no parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a constructor for that class that has no arguments. The only constructor you have takes parameters. Add this to your class:

```
public CharityCyclists() { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the `CharityCyclists` class:

```
public CharityCyclists()
{
}
```

You can't code the line:

```
CharityCyclists cyclist1 = new CharityCyclists();
```

unless you have that constructor.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET, a no args (parameterless) constructor implicitly exists if no other constructors have been declared. Once you declare a constructor with parameters, you must also explicitly declare another constructor with no parameters for your code to continue compiling.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to instantiate cyclist1 an instance of CharityCyclists class without any
arguments - that requires a constructor with no arguments.

But the definition of the CharityCyclists class only has one constructor with 9 arguments.  Since that constructor requires 9 arguments, cyclist1  will not match that constructor.  You need a constructor that takes no arguments as in:

```
public CharityCyclists()
{
    this.bicycle ="";
    this.wheels = 0;       
    this.FundsRaised = 0.0;
}
```