# Getting error: The type ___ does not contain a constructor that takes '0' arguments

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a system for save and load store in a game. The problem I'm facing:

> The type 'dataToBeSaved' does not contain a constructor that takes '0' arguments

The problem is on this line: `datosAguardar datos = new datosAguardar ();` and here is my code :

```
public int puntuacionMaxima = 0;

public static estadoJuego estadojuego; 

private string rutaArchivo; 

void Awake ()
{
    rutaArchivo = Application.persistentDataPath + "/datos.dat";
    if (estadojuego == null) 
    {
        estadojuego = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad (gameObject);

    }  else if (estadojuego != this) 
    {
        Destroy (gameObject);
    }

}

// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{
    cargar ();

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

public void guardar ()
{

    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter ();
    FileStream file = File.Create (rutaArchivo);

    datosAguardar datos = new datosAguardar ();
    datos.puntuacionMaxima = puntuacionMaxima; 

    bf.Serialize (file, datos);

    file.Close ();

}


void cargar () 
{
    if (File.Exists (rutaArchivo)) 
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter ();
        FileStream file = File.Open (rutaArchivo,FileMode.Open);

        datosAguardar datos = (datosAguardar)bf.Deserialize (file);

        puntuacionMaxima = datos.puntuacionMaxima; 

        file.Close ();
    }  else 
    {
        puntuacionMaxima = 0; 
    }
}


[Serializable]
class datosAguardar
{
    public int puntuacionMaxima ; 

    public datosAguardar (int puntuacionMaxima)
    {
        this.puntuacionMaxima = puntuacionMaxima ; 
    }
}
```

Comment: your constructor is `public datosAguardar (int puntuacionMaxima)` which takes 1 argument. The error is explicit: you have to pass 1 argument to the constructor you've written...

Comment: Or provide a second constructor without args

Comment: Note that if there are no constructor declarations in a class definition, the default constructor (constructor with no arguments) is implicitly defined. However, since there is one here (`public datosAguardar (int puntuacionMaxima)`), you need to explicitly define the default constructor yourself, or only use the constructor with the argument.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting a "does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments" error? C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13260021/why-am-i-getting-a-does-not-contain-a-constructor-that-takes-0-arguments-error). (There are tons of possible dupe targets, this was the closest to the situation I found on cursory search.)